# Is $\frac{2}{π}(\sin t+\cos t)$ the same as $\frac{4}{π\sqrt2}\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I've been solving some problems on signals for practice and I solved a particular one in two ways. The first way gave me this result : 
$$V(t)=\frac{2}{π}(\sin t+\cos t)$$

The second way gave:  $$V(t)=\frac{4}{π\sqrt2}\sin\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

Plotting this two online they seem to be the same. How can I prove this mathematically? I haven't used trigonometric formulas much so I don't have many ideas. I tried turning the sint to a cosine and then applying the addition formula of cosa+cosb but that doesn't help.

Comment: [Angle sum and difference identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that

$$\sin (t+\pi/4)=\sin t\cos (\pi/4)+\cos t\sin (\pi/4)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1:$$$$$2$ functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are considered equal if and only if they have the same domain $D$, and the same value of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for any $x\in D$. 
$$$$
Hint 2:$$$$
$V_1(t)=\frac{2}{π}(\sin t+\cos t)$ and $V_2(t)=\frac{4}{π\sqrt2}\sin(t+π/4)$ have the same domain ($R$ - the set of Real Numbers).
$$$$
Hint 3:
$$$$
$$V_1(t)=\frac{2}{π}(\sin t+\cos t)=\dfrac{2\sqrt 2}{\pi}\left(\dfrac{\sin t}{\sqrt 2}+\dfrac{\cos t}{\sqrt 2}\right)=\frac{4}{π\sqrt2}sin(t+π/4)=V_2(t)$$
$$$$
Note that $\sin (t+\pi/4)=\sin t\cos(\pi/4)+\sin(\pi/4)\cos t$

Comment: Why must you use 3 empty lines? Also, use `\sin x` instead of `sin x` for LaTeX formatting.